# nginx.conf file for ending rtmp live stream to Nginx and publish as HLS to embed into website

Tags: windows, nginx, nginx-location

I'm using a Windows version of Nginx and, as said in the title, I have problems with the file nginx.config. I couldn't find documentation for my problem, I only found nginx.conf files for Ubuntu. So my question is: how should I change my nginx.conf file according to Windows? This is my nginx file so far:

```
    #user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }


        location /hls {
            # Serve HLS fragments
            types {
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }
            root /tmp;
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }

}

rtmp {

    server {

        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 8192;
        ping 30s;
        notify_method get;
        allow play all;

        application hls {
        allow play all;
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_path /tmp/hls;
        }

        # MPEG-DASH is similar to HLS

        #application dash {
        #    live on;
        #    dash on;
        #    dash_path /tmp/dash;
        #}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

nginx.conf for windows

```
worker_processes  auto;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application live {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path "G:/TV-SERVER-HLS/nginxgraphyon/html/hls/";
            hls_fragment 10s;
            hls_playlist_length 20s;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }
    }
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    directio 512;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
      listen 8080;

      location / {
        index index.html;
      } 
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location /hls {
            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
                text/html html;

            }

            root "G:/TV-SERVER-HLS/nginxgraphyon/html/";

        }
    }
}
```